# Volume and surfaces

Tags: surfaces, volume

i need help.

Be : $X =(x,y,z)$ and

$$T=\{x\in R^3\mid X=\begin{bmatrix}(1+rsin(u))cos(v)\\(1+rsin(u))sin(v)\\rcos(v)\end{bmatrix} ,\\0.5\geq r \geq 0,\\ 2\pi\geq u \geq 0 \\ 2 \pi\geq v \geq0 $$

and $$V(X)=\begin{bmatrix}x-sin(y)\\xz^2+y\\cos(x)+z\end{bmatrix}$$

a) they shall calculate the volume of T

b) they determine the flow of v by the surface of T ie $ \int_{\partial T}^{} V(X).n_a \,dO$ ,the normal $n_a$ show outward

I tried to solve it but I got difficulties, So only the task b, the task a I managed

Comment: $T$ has 3 variables ? and $v(t)$ is the same $v$ in $T$? why to use $x$ either for the position vector and one of its components. Better you rearrange the notation.

Comment: **that's better?**

Comment: yes a bit better, but still, why $3$ variables for $T$ ? (should maybe be two, $r$ fixed?) and where does the $t$ come from? How did you calculate a)?

Comment: yes true, you're right, I have corrected it